# Reference for $(N_1\cap N_2)\otimes_A M = (N_1\otimes_A M)\cap ( N_2\otimes_A M)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Where can I find a canonical proof of the following statement?

> If $M$ is a flat $A$-module and $N$ is an $A$-module with submodules $N_1, N_2$, then $$(N_1\cap N_2)\otimes_A M = (N_1\otimes_A M)\cap (N_2\otimes_A M)$$ inside $N \otimes_A M$.

This is a standard proposition in commutative algebra, so I expect it can be found in a textbook.  I would like to know so that I can study this proof in detail until I understand it.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for the containment $(N_1 \cap N_2) \otimes_A M \subset N_1 \otimes_A M$. But this is just the fact that tensoring with $M$ preserves inclusions (by flatness).

Comment: $- \otimes_A M$ preserves finite limits and intersections are finite limits.

Comment: Ah, the question makes more sense now that the typo is fixed...

Answer (score 1):

This is Theorem 7.4(i) in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory* (on page 48).

The proof is simple enough that I may as well include it here.

> Take $$\begin{array}{rcrcc}
> \varphi&:&N&\rightarrow &N/N_1\oplus N/N_2 \\
> &&x&\mapsto &(x+N_1,x+N_2)\end{array}$$
>   and the sequence $$0\rightarrow N_1\cap N_2 \rightarrow N \overset{\varphi}{\rightarrow} \frac{N}{N_1}\oplus \frac{N}{N_2}\rightarrow 0$$ is exact.  Since $M$ is flat, we then have that $$0\rightarrow (N_1\cap N_2)\otimes_A M \rightarrow N\otimes_A M  \overset{\varphi\otimes 1}{\rightarrow} \frac{N\otimes_A M}{N_1\otimes_A M} \oplus \frac{N\otimes_A M}{N_2\otimes_A M} \rightarrow 0$$
>   is exact, and that's what we wanted to show.

Comment: What is your $N$? The map your defined in line 2 is not neccessarily surjective, so you cannot conclude that the induced sequence is exact. Instead, the sequence is exact at $N$ and then we have the second sequence is exact at $N\otimes M$. Then we win.

Comment: @user119882 Can you provide a counterexample? I copied the proof (nearly) verbatim from Matsumura.  They're his maps.

Comment: For example $N_1=N_2=0,N=A$. We don't need the map $\phi$ being surjective. What we need is the sequence $0\rightarrow N_1\cap N_2 \rightarrow N \overset{\varphi}{\rightarrow} \frac{N}{N_1}\oplus \frac{N}{N_2}$ is exact. (Which was same as Matsumura's book). That is the difference between your answer and the proof in the book.

Comment: @user119882 Ohhh, I see, the issue is with my use of "induced."  I should read more carefully, thanks.